# Inserting the value of raw_input into os.system command

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the data of my raw_input into my os.system() command.
This is my code.

```
def sess_menu():
os.system('clear')
banner()
print colors["white"] + "Select Ovpn Config!!\n"
for file in os.listdir("ovpnconfs/"):
  if file.endswith(".ovpn"):
     print colors["magenta"] + (os.path.join(file))

     print colors["white"] + "\n[9] Back"
vprofile = raw_input("[-] Choose: ")
    ovpn_profile()
return
```

here's my function calling it, I can't seem to find a way to get the data into my command

```
def ovpn_profile():
os.system("openvpn --config ovpnconfs/*raw_input data*")
```

Comment: `raw_input` not `raw_imput`. I thought it was a typo in your title but you use it throughout.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `; sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` (`os.system` + user input is asking for trouble)

Comment: yes sorry , im french and always make the mistake with this word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters

```
def ovpn_profile(profile):
    os.system('openvpn --config ovpnconfs/"{0}"'.format(profile))

vprofile = raw_input("[-] Choose: ")
ovpn_profile(vprofile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work,

```
def ovpn_profile():
   os.system("openvpn --config ovpnconfs/{0}".format(vprofile))
```